# rufus scheduler is not sending messages at scheduled time in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rufus-scheduler

I am using rufus scheduler gem to run background jobs. I am using this gem to send messages and images to twitter and facebook.
below is my code

```
def schedule_post_to_twitter(twitter_auth, file=nil)
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
    scheduler.at self.post_at do
       if file.present?
         self.post_to_twitter(twitter_auth,file)
       else
      self.post_to_twitter(twitter_auth)
     end
  end
end
```

suppose i will schdule the message at "2014-03-18 12:23:02" In development it posts the message at 12.23 itself, but in production it is posting immediately. scheduling is not working in production. please help me how to make this working in production.

Comment: please indicate what version of Ruby and rufus-scheduler you are using. Please indicate what server (Webrick, Thin, Passenger, ...) you are running Rails on top of (and its version). You say "in production it is posting immediately", have you checked the clock of your production server, is it the expected timezone ?

Comment: yes checked the timezone, but it is posting immediately.

Comment: rufus-scheduler triggers immediately when the "at" is in the past. Double check what you are passing to it.

Comment: what i have to check? timezone?

Comment: the value you have in the "post_at".

Comment: post_at is "2014-03-18 19:32:00",and time zone is Chennai

Comment: go on investigating that. Quoting myself: "rufus-scheduler triggers immediately when the "at" is in the past". That's the hint for you.

Answer (score 0):

So you're creating a new rufus scheduler for each schedule... That's a bad idea, it's wasting resources. A single, shared, rufus-scheduler is sufficient.

Please read the doc at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#so-rails to see how to setup a rufus-scheduler instance via a Rails initializer. The example there is scheduling from a controller, feel free to schedule from your model method as you intend.

Mandatory read as well: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when rufus-scheduler triggers immediately, it means the "at" is in the past.

Try with this code to see if that hypothesis holds or not:

```
def schedule_post_to_twitter(twitter_auth, file=nil)
  scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new # suicidal technique
  scheduler.at self.post_at do
    #if file.present?
    #  self.post_to_twitter(twitter_auth, file)
    #else
    #  self.post_to_twitter(twitter_auth)
    #end
    p [ :post_at, self.post_at ]
    p [ :post_at, Rufus::Scheduler.parse(self.post_at) ]
    p [ :now, Time.now ]
  end
end
```

And please read my other answer. It's dangerous to start a new rufus-scheduler instance for each schedule...